# ThinkScript to Python - iterative for loop, having trouble

Tags: python, for-loop, thinkscript

I am trying to translate the following code from ThinkScript (TD Ameritrade code) to Python, and am having trouble getting it to output the right shape.

**ThinkScript:**

This code in TDA outputs a line bound by "`lengtha`", -10, 10.  Using "`fold`", it iterates between the previous 10 open prices and compares them to the current close price. Depending on the iterative output the loop adds or subtracts 1 from "`s`", where "`s`" is zero initially by default.

For example if `ca > GetValue(oa, i)` is `true` for the last 10 `oa` values, the output is 10.

**I would like to translate this into python, where `oa` and `ca` are numpy arrays. And, where the output is another numpy array of equivalent detention as `oa` and `ca`**

```
input lengtha = 10;
def oa = open();
def ca = close();
def data = fold i = 0 to lengtha
           with s
           do s + (if ca > GetValue(oa, i)
                   then 1
                   else if ca < GetValue(oa, i)
                        then - 1
                        else 0);
```

**What I have tried:**

This is one of many version of this I have tried. This particular one does appear to go through the math in the way that I expect (possibly).  However, it outputs an array of arrays, where I would like to simply return 1 value for each value in `ca`.

```
    oa = np.array(open)
    ca = np.array(close)

    window_size = 10
    running_count = 0
    result = []
    for i in range(window_size):
        oa_window = oa[i:i+window_size]
        ca_window = ca
        window_result = np.where(ca_window > oa_window, running_count+1, running_count-1)
        running_count += np.sum(np.where(ca_window > oa_window, 1, -1))
        running_count = min(max(running_count, -10), 10)
        result.append(window_result)
    result = np.array(result)
    print(result)
```

**Output:**

1. I'm unsure how this results in -11's.
2. I'm unsure how to return a result as a 1 by `X` (1D) array, rather than this 10 by `X` by 10.
   (where `X` is the size of `ca` and `oa`)

```
[[[ -1   1  -1 ...   1   1  -1]
  [  1   1  -1 ...   1   1   1]
  [ -1   1  -1 ...   1   1   1]
  ...
  [ -1  -1  -1 ...  -1  -1  -1]
  [ -1  -1  -1 ...  -1  -1  -1]
  [ -1  -1  -1 ...  -1  -1  -1]]

 [[ -9 -11 -11 ...  -9 -11 -11]
  [ -9 -11  -9 ...  -9  -9  -9]
  [ -9 -11  -9 ...  -9  -9 -11]
  ...
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]]

 [[-11 -11  -9 ... -11 -11  -9]
  [-11  -9  -9 ...  -9  -9  -9]
  [-11  -9  -9 ...  -9 -11  -9]
  ...
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]]

 ...

 [[ -9  -9 -11 ...  -9  -9  -9]
  [ -9  -9  -9 ...  -9  -9  -9]
  [ -9  -9  -9 ...  -9  -9  -9]
  ...
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]]

 [[ -9 -11 -11 ...  -9  -9  -9]
  [ -9  -9  -9 ...  -9  -9  -9]
  [ -9  -9 -11 ...  -9  -9  -9]
  ...
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]]

 [[-11 -11  -9 ...  -9  -9  -9]
  [ -9  -9  -9 ...  -9  -9  -9]
  [ -9 -11  -9 ...  -9  -9  -9]
  ...
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]
  [-11 -11 -11 ... -11 -11 -11]]]
```

Desired Output:
(random examples)

```
[ 1
 -8
  3
  9
  10
  0
 . . . 
 -10
 -9 ]
```

**Possible Solution**

Spent some more time on this and this formula looks like it may be doing what I want:

This doesn't quite get to the output I'm looking for though. Seems like it gets stuck at -10 for a long time.

```
    for j in range(i-10, i):
        sum += np.where(ca > oa[j], 1, np.where(ca < oa[j], -1, 0))
```

Comment: Spend a lot more time on this.

This looks like it may be doing what I want it to: 

    for j in range(i-10, i):
        sum += np.where(ca > oa[j], 1, np.where(ca < oa[j], -1, 0))

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out I think. the addition of `np.roll()` brought it home.

```
for j in range(0, 10):
    sum += np.where(ca > np.roll(oa,j), 1, np.where(ca < np.roll(oa,j), -1, 0))
```